# Is there a way to define a class in a method in C#?

Tags: c#

As far as *I* can see it is not possible.

But on the other hand it is not possible to create a function in a function in C# either; [unless](https://www.selfelected.com/function-within-a-method-in-c-csharp-dotnet/) one [tries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884412/521554), that [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135121/521554). These lambda functions behave like ordinary functions.
Proper structs are not possible according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205907/is-it-possible-to-define-a-local-struct-within-a-method-in-c) question on SO. The solution presented for structs doesn't declare a type but an anonymous one.
One can use `Tuple<>` to get type safety but it is a bit hard to understand the content of `myCustomer.Item1`.

Now neither functions nor structs are classes and I hope someone have invented a clever trick somewhere.

I would like something like:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    class MyClass
    {
        ...
    }
    var x = new MyClass();
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to create a class inside a function, however using lambdas it is possible to define a function inside a function as the links you posted suggest.

Comment: What's the motivating example? What *problem* are you facing such that "oh, if I could just declare a class from within a function, this would be easily solved" is the correct reaction?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Instead of littering the class with helper classes I can keep them inside the method. I can also have two classes "Result" but with different signatures; since they are hidden inside the method. It is not a matter of 'easily solved' but one of information hiding and readability.

Comment: But you're still not offering any specific examples here. Bear in mind that every feature starts at [minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx). Java had a "need" for such classes because they didn't have delegates.